# How to return CLOB as OUT parameter in ORACLE stored procedure

Tags: xml, oracle, stored-procedures

I want to return an XML output for my stored procedure in Oracle SQL Developer and I want to return this as CLOB datatype(Suggest me if there is any better approach than CLOB).
I tried to google but couldn't find any helpful resource.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how exactly is your data stored? you can store XML as a CLOB for instance. The OUT param as a CLOB bit is fairly straightforward. Converting your data to a CLOB is also pretty easy as there are functions like getClobVal()

Comment: Yes, I will store XML as a CLOB and return as OUT param. I am very much new to Oracle so unable to figure it out

Comment: you will find this resource valuable too I think https://community.oracle.com/community/development_tools/xml/pl_sql_xml_programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example.

```
CREATE TABLE "XML_STUFF" 
   (    "COLUMN1" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "XML_STUFF" "SYS"."XMLTYPE" , 
     CONSTRAINT "XML_STUFF_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("COLUMN1")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" 
 XMLTYPE COLUMN "XML_STUFF" STORE AS SECUREFILE CLOB (
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192
  NOCACHE LOGGING  NOCOMPRESS  KEEP_DUPLICATES 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 106496 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) ;

-- insert some XML/records into your table

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OUT_XML 
(
  PARAM1 IN INTEGER 
, PARAM2 OUT CLOB 
) AS 
 xml_bits xmltype;
BEGIN
  select xml_stuff into xml_bits 
  from demo.xml_stuff
  where column1 = param1;

  param2 := xml_bits.getclobval();
  dbms_output.put_line(param2); -- this is just here to make it easier to 'see'
END OUT_XML;

--run it!

DECLARE
  PARAM1 NUMBER;
  PARAM2 CLOB;
BEGIN
  PARAM1 := 1;

  DEMO.OUT_XML(
    PARAM1 => PARAM1,
    PARAM2 => PARAM2
  );
  /* Legacy output: 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PARAM2 = ' || PARAM2);
*/ 
  :PARAM2 := PARAM2;
--rollback; 
END;
```

[image]

Comment: How to deal the same when my column datatype(where my XML is stored) in the table is clob.(Here in your example the XML data is saved in xmltype datatype column, XML_STUFF).

Comment: Its throwing an error for CLOB datatype:Error(9,10): PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CLOB

Comment: if it's just a clob, no need for the function call getclobval(). what/why are you trying to pass a CLOB to a number?

Comment: modified accordingly and my updated stored procedure looks as edited in my question.Please refer.